# why django makemigrations can not detect my models

Tags: python, django, orm

1. create a empty database in mysql
2. create a project
3. create a app named test_mod
4. creare a dir mod in test_mod, with **init**.py and mod.py in mod dir, and a simple model class(mod_test) declared in mod.py

   ```
   test_mod

   ---views.py

   ---models.py

   ---mod

   ------mod.py

   ------__init__.py
   ```
5. add app test_mod to `INSTALLED_APP`, and do a makemigrations, there are no changes be detected. and migrate will not create `test_mod_mod_test` table in database
6. insert a statement into `test_mod.models.py` (a file create by startapp command):

   ```
    from mod.mod import test_mod
   ```
7. now the `makemigrations` will detect the model `mod_test`, but if the statement in step 6 was insert into `views.py` (any file except `models.py`), the mod_test will not be detected.
8. test in django 1.7 and 1.8, same result.
   I get confused by this, and no interpretation was found from django official document.
   I am gratful for any hints and help.
   thanks.

Comment: What if you change the import to `from .mod.mod import *`?
BTW there might me a typo either in the explanation (point 4, name of the class) and the import.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to create an `__init__.py` file in every directory of your project for python to recognize those directories as modules. Add `__init__.py` to the root level of the `test_mod` directory.
- Declare all your model classes for this application (app) in the `models.py` file. It is the accepted solution for model files. Why you need to declare an addition models class in another file and/or sub-directory?

Comment: I add a __initi__.py files in every dir, but still no changes detected. write all models in models.py? so inflexible.